# safeDump Anchors in js-yaml

Tags: javascript, yaml, node-modules

I got the following `yaml` file

```yaml
center: &center
  vertical: 15

css:
  - text: 'System'
    alignment: *center
  - text: 'Monitor'
    alignment: *center
```

I am trying to add another node to `css` using `js-yaml` using the code below

```js
const yaml = require('js-yaml')
const fs = require('fs')

try {
  const doc = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('css.yml', 'utf8'))
  doc.css.push({
    text: 'Keyboard',
    alignment: *center
  })
  const yamlStr = yaml.safeDump(doc)
  fs.writeFileSync('css.yml', yamlStr, 'utf8');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

How do i reference the `alignment` property?  as `*center` is ofcourse not working

Cheers